# Finding the image of a region transformed by a mapping

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, transformation

[image]

The only examples I've found are either very complicated, or state the transformation like y=g(u,v) x=f(u,v), whereas this question states u and v in terms of x and y.

I'm not sure how to get started. If I use F to solve for x and y in terms of u and v, sqrt($x^{2}+y^{2}$) will still have a y in it, and vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Convert the coordinates into polar form.

Comment: Which ones? For the bounds, I get: r^2=1, (let p=theta) p=pi*k-pi/6, p=pi*k-3pi/4.   For the new coordinates, I get: u=|r|, v=p (when -pi/2 < p <pi/2). What do I do with this information?

Comment: If I transform the boundaries using F, I get: 1) r=1 2) 1/4 < k < 5/4 and 3) -1/2 < k < 2/3 .   Are these my new x and y values? What does it mean? How do I graph the new region?

Comment: @Bob So by converting to polar, you get $0\le r\le 1$ and $\frac{\pi}{4}\le \theta\le \frac{2\pi}{3}$ (I am not sure what you mean by $k$). Then applying the transformation you get $u=r$ and $v=\theta$. Hence the new region is just the rectangle bounded by the lines $x=0$, $x=1$, $y=\frac{\pi}{4}$, and $y=\frac{2\pi}{3}$. Does this make sense?

Comment: @Bob Oh, sorry, actually the above is not quite right. You do need to break up into cases where $\frac{\pi}{4}\le\theta\le\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}<\theta\le\frac{2\pi}{3}$ because of the domain of arctangent. But the idea that you get rectangles is the same.

Comment: Oops, I was taking multiple solutions for theta. Yes, I think I understand. You get the new lines by taking the extremes for the ranges of r and theta, and plug them into the transformation. Thank you!

Comment: Except why is 0<r<1. Isn't it just r= +/- 1 ?

Comment: unit circle: $x^{2}+y^{2}=1$ => $(rcosx)^{2}+(rsinx)^{2}=1$ => $(r)^{2}(1)=1$ => $(r)^{2}=1$  => r = +/- 1

Comment: @Bob I'm being really silly today: Correction to my correction: We should be looking at $\frac{\pi}{4}\le\theta\le\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\frac{-\pi}{2}\le\theta\le\frac{-\pi}{3}$ because of the $\textit{range}$ of the arc tangent function. In answer to your latest question: I interpreted "bounded by the unit circle" to mean any points inside the unit circle and inside the given lines - so that the region we are exmining looks like a slice of cake. Hence the $0\le r\le1$. Additionally, in polar coordinates we always have $r\ge 0$ because combined with $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$ we can reach any point

Comment: Ohh so it should be $x^{2}+y^{2} <= 1$ making r <= 1. I see.  And I understand your correction. Thank you.

Comment: The region will be separated into 2, yes?

Comment: @Bob 2 rectangles, yes.